# Concatenate Boost Hana strings

Tags: c++, boost-hana

Trying to concatenate Boost Hana compile-time strings gives compiler errors in my application. Is there any particular configuration option to activate or header that needs to be included for this to work?

Here is one example:

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL
#include "boost/hana.hpp"

namespace hana = boost::hana;

using namespace hana::literals;

int main() {
  auto t = "left, "_s + "right"_s;
}
```

This fails with error `error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘boost::hana::string<'l', 'e', 'f', 't', ',', ' '>’ and ‘boost::hana::string<'r', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't'>’)`
 on GCC 6.3.1. with Hana from Boost 1.62.0

As a side note, replacing the operator `+` with `hana::plus` fails with error `hana::plus(x, y) requires 'x' to be a Monoid`

Comment: [Works in Boost 1.63.](https://wandbox.org/permlink/LDuI2ykh0b4HC5OC)

Comment: Yeah it was added in 1.63. https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/7a3e0480d442c393ed7bcc1ca72a3e1821319ff0

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Jason Rice, support for compile-time string concatenation was added in Boost 1.63

https://github.com/boostorg/hana/commit/7a3e0480d442c393ed7bcc1ca72a3e1821319ff0